# How to do a get request in Micropython on ESP32?

Tags: python, python-requests, esp32, micropython

I'm trying to do a simple get request with Micropython on an ESP32. Unfortunately I keep getting `OSError: -202`.

That's what I have so far:

wlan.py

```
import network

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF) # create station interface
wlan.active(True)       # activate the interface
wlan.connect('Schmittli', 'the key') # connect to an AP
wlan.ifconfig()         # get the interface's IP/netmask/gw/DNS addresses
```

And this is the REPL output:

```
>>> import wlan
import wlan
I (19080) wifi:wifi driver task: 3ffd1058, prio:23, stack:3584, core=0
I (38466) system_api: Base MAC address is not set, read default base MAC address from BLK0 of EFUSE
I (38466) system_api: Base MAC address is not set, read default base MAC address from BLK0 of EFUSE
I (38506) wifi:wifi firmware version: 44aa95c
I (38506) wifi:config NVS flash: enabled
I (38506) wifi:config nano formating: disabled
I (38506) wifi:Init dynamic tx buffer num: 32
I (38506) wifi:Init data frame dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (38516) wifi:Init management frame dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (38516) wifi:Init management short buffer num: 32
I (38526) wifi:Init static rx buffer size: 1600
I (38526) wifi:Init static rx buffer num: 10
I (38536) wifi:Init dynamic rx buffer num: 32
W (38536) phy_init: failed to load RF calibration data (0x1102), falling back to full calibration
I (38676) phy: phy_version: 4180, cb3948e, Sep 12 2019, 16:39:13, 0, 2
I (38696) wifi:mode : sta (30:ae:a4:f6:0f:08)
I (38696) wifi: STA_START
>>> I (38816) wifi:new:<1,0>, old:<1,0>, ap:<255,255>, sta:<1,0>, prof:1
I (39666) wifi:state: init -> auth (b0)
I (39676) wifi:state: auth -> assoc (0)
I (39686) wifi:state: assoc -> run (10)
I (39706) wifi:connected with Schmittli, aid = 28, channel 1, BW20, bssid = a0:b5:49:00:c6:cd
I (39706) wifi:security type: 3, phy: bgn, rssi: -53
I (39706) wifi:pm start, type: 1

I (39716) network: CONNECTED
I (39776) wifi:AP's beacon interval = 102400 us, DTIM period = 3
I (42456) event: sta ip: 192.168.1.118, mask: 255.255.255.0, gw: 192.168.1.1
I (42456) network: GOT_IP


>>> import urequests
import urequests
I (72686) modsocket: Initializing
>>> response = urequests.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1')
response = urequests.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "urequests.py", line 108, in get
  File "urequests.py", line 53, in request
OSError: -202
```

I tried with two different ESP32 boards, so I don't think this is not a hardware problem. And yes, the URL works fine in my browser.

**Update**

Requesting the same service with it's IP address works. So it's a DNS Problem. I have 10+ diffrent devices on the same WLAN. All are working fine. So I really think this is a Mircopython problem.

This is the configuration, after the ESP32 connects to the WLAN:

```
>>> wlan.ifconfig()
wlan.ifconfig()
('192.168.1.116', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.1.1', '42.2.18.11')
```

In all my other devices the DNS server is '192.168.1.1'. I tried to set the DNS server manually in the ESP32, but that does not work:

```
>>> wlan.ifconfig('192.168.1.116', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1')
wlan.ifconfig('192.168.1.116', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: function expected at most 2 arguments, got 5
>>> wlan.status()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try solution from with one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64098376/getting-oserror-202-where-running-urequests-get-from-micropy ?

Comment: I'm manually waiting for the connection, and the output states `I (39716) network: CONNECTED`, But I tried anyway. No change, I still get `OSError: -202`.

Comment: everything still seems to point to you WLAN configuration : your DHCP server hands out a different DNS server (42.2.18.11 = 42-2-18-011.static.netvigator.com) that is not allowing access to port 53 for DNS services.
I would suggest you focus on getting the DHCP / network configuration resolved so that your MicroPython Board gets the proper dns server assigned.

Comment: the synx used in trying to set a static Ip & DNS is incorrect, you are missing (). ifconfig expects a tuple, not 4 parameters. (I agree the error could be clearer)  `wlan.ifconfig(('192.168.1.116', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1')`)` should do better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you DNS server is not resolving the fqdn to an IP address for some reason.

- run `print(wlan.ifconfig())` to check your assigned DNS server in the [last nibble](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/tutorial/network_basics.html?highlight=ifconfig)
- check if your DNS server perhaps is configured to filter queries from the specific client / subnet
- resolve the FQDN to IP on a different client (your PC) , and use that IP address in MicroPython. If that works your DNS is the problem
- you can also test your DNS using :

```py
import socket
print(socket.getaddrinfo('micropython.org', 80))
print(socket.getaddrinfo('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', 80))
# sample return
[(2, 1, 0, 'micropython.org', ('176.58.119.26', 80))]
[(2, 1, 0, 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', ('104.27.188.192', 80))]
```

If it is not your name resolution, you might be hitting a firewall.

Comment: You are right. DNS ist not working. But why? I have iOS, OSX, RaperyPIs, Android and Windows devices on the same WLAN. They all work without problems.

Comment: is there any way to bypass the firewall problem? My service is running on the domain name which is resolved by our internal DNS server, I guess, cause using IP resolved by getAddrinfo on the browser does not work for obvious reason. I there any option to use microphython HTTP requests with the domain name and not IP?

Comment: in short: if you cannot resolve names to ip addresses , then you can't use names

Answer (score 0):

add only two argument in wlan.ifconfig('192.168.4.1', '192.168.1.116')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).